# Is the line through $(-4, -6, 1)$ and $(-2, 0, -3)$ parallel to the line through $(10, 18, 4)$ and $(5, 3, 14)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Problem statement:

> Is the line through $(-4, -6, 1)$ and $(-2, 0, -3)$ parallel to the
>   line through $(10, 18, 4)$ and $(5, 3, 14)$?

My attempt:

For the first line, we know the vector equation for the line is 
$$\overrightarrow{v}_1 = (-2, 0, -3) + t[(-4, -6, 1) - (-2, 0, -3)] = (-2-2t, -6t, -3+4t)$$
and for the second line, 
$$\overrightarrow{v}_2 = (10, 18, 4) + t[(5, 3, 14)-(10, 18, 4)] = (10-5t, 18-15t, 4+10t)$$
and since these two vector equations are not scale multiples of each other, they are not parallel.

But Stewart says they are.

Where did I go wrong?

[In particular, it would be nice to know if my subtraction order is correct.]

Comment: It might be easier to not find the vector equation of the line and instead just the direction vector of the line. That might help eliminate any arithmetic mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the subtraction order does not matter for this problem.

Second, **hint**: can you write down a vector which gives the direction of the first line?  Note that it is not
$$(-2-2t, 6t, -3+4t)\ ,$$
this is a vector *from the origin to the line*.

Comment: Would not have thought that was necessary.  From the vector equation$${\bf v}_1=(-2,0,-3)+t(-2,6,4)\ ,$$or directly from the given information, you should be able to write down with no further calculation, a vector in the direction of the line.

Comment: Any scalar multiple of $(-2, 6, 4)$ is a direction vector?

Comment: (assuming the scalar is $>0$, of course)

Comment: Any scalar at all, including negatives.  The question asked about lines being parallel, not vectors.  (The scalar multiple can't be zero though - in that case one of the "lines" would not really be a line.)

Comment: Ah, thank you. By the way, I realized just now that there's a typo in the original problem... Thanks again!